# Firebase notifications when app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have implemented Firebase notification in my Android application. When my app is running, notification is displayed with my custom layout, but when application is not running, the notification is displayed with the default layout. How can I change the notification layout to my layout when application is not running. Also, I store shared preferences to let user toggle notifications. But when app is not running the notification is displayed anyways. How can achieve that?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(SettingsFragment.getReceiceNotification()){ //if user wants to receive notification

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.push_notification_layout);

    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.push_notif_icon,R.mipmap.ic_bird_black);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Radyo Türkkuşu");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.push_title, "Radyo Türkkuşu");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.push_context, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //notificationBuilder.setLights (ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.context, R.color.pushColor), 5000, 5000);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I am asking for technical information, do not want implementation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your problem is you using it with notification tray.

See this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

> Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

If you using `{data:"something"}(data-message)` with `{notification:"something"}(display-message)` while your app is in background the data payload will delivered to extras of the intent but not to the `onMessageReceived()` method.I assume you implement your code for showing notification, so when your app is in foreground `onMessageReceived()` is trigger and it display the desire notification you want but when it is not `onMessageReceived()` no get trigger instead android system will handle it with your notification payload. You just have remove `{notification:"something"}(display-message/notification tray)` from your server side code to always ensure `onMessageReceived()`.

For anyone keep mention `onMessageReceived()` will always trigger no matter wether it is not foreground or background please visit this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background)

Comment: Are you using firebase console for sending message?

Comment: Yes I do use the console.

Comment: That why. You have to use server side code to handle the request. As far as i know console always use notification payload.

Comment: @teckwei Correct, the data you can send in the console is the body field of a notification

Answer (score 13):

There are two types of FCM messages

1. Notification message
2. Data message

Messages which get sent from Firebase console are **Notification message**. In order to get message in onMessageReceived() use **Data Message**. Use below code at server side to send Data Notification message

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }
```

Reference  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: Exactly. The documentation says that if Notification Payload is sent in the message, then FCM will handle the notification on the device on behalf of the client app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should never be triggered when your app is closed or running in the background. See this:[Firebase Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

What you need to do is check how the app start up, tap the notification or tap the launcher icon. To do this, some data should be add into the notification then retrieve them in the first start activity in your app. If you can retrieve them successfully, it means your app is launched by tapping the notification, then you can do what you want to do.